Issue Accessing ADLS Mounted Location Using All-Purpose Cluster in Azure Data Factory
I am able to access an ADLS mounted location from Databricks when running my notebook via Azure Data Factory using a Job Cluster (created by Databricks). However, when I switch to using an All-Purpose Cluster in the Azure Data Factory configuration, I am unable to access the ADLS mounted location from Databricks.
I have verified below things already but do not know what is the issue? Would appreciate any help or suggestions:

I verified if ADF managed identity have access to external location.
Mounting Configuration.
Cluster Permissions: From within My Databricks notebook, I tried accessing the ADLS mount by running a simple command like "dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/your_mount_point")


can you add error you are getting?

how you are authenticating and creating mountpoint

I tried the same in my environment and it is working for me with both job cluster and all-purpose cluster:

Execution with All-purpose cluster:


Execution with job cluster:


Once check if you are able to connect the ADLS using mountpoint in Databricks notebook via all-purpose cluster in databricks workspace.

Try re-creating mountpoint for ADLS and connect it with All-Purpose Cluster to make sure it uses the correct credentials.

If you have configured cluster-level policies in Databricks, check if these policies are same for both Job Clusters and All-Purpose Clusters.


